# What is Azure Redis Cache?

Tags: azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

What is Azure REDIS Cache? How to use it? When to use and when not to use it? Can I use it for a simple c# application which accesses data from MS-SQL server?
What is best source to get started with Azure Redis cache?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cache/?

Comment: Yes but what I am not getting is when to use it?

Comment: when will you use caching ? in that scenario you can use redis cache for applications running in cache.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Redis Cache offering is a Software as a service (SAAS) offering of the opensource Redis cache. You should be able to get started with the resource below:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cache/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/services/redis-cache/

http://redis.io/documentation

There is good support for C# via 'StackExchange.Redis' [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis/) package. However, please explore if your application needs or will benefit from a cache solution before you get to the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Cache for Redis provides an in-memory data store based on the Redis software. Redis improves the performance and scalability of an application that uses backend data stores heavily
In my application I have stored around 5 millions key/value data with each key containing around 800 records in json format under Redis cache. Called the Redis using stackexchange library(1.2.6) since the application does not support the latest version

You can go through the below links

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-redis-samples